# Drawing a simple shape with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL on Java but am having some problems.

I've looked through numerous  tutorials but most information that I've found uses either deprecated methods or it c++ specific.

I want to display a simple triangle, and my code doesn't seem to work.

It compiles but only displays a frame.

Please help. I would also appreciate any good sources for further reading(since I couldn't find any).

Thank you.

```
public class JOGL extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {
    int width = 600;
    int height = 600;

    static float[] vertices_position = {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f,
    };

    FloatBuffer bufPos = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices_position);

    int vertexbuffer[] = new int[1];

    public JOGL() {
        super("Minimal OpenGL");
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);

        this.setName("Minimal OpenGL");
        this.getContentPane().add(canvas);

        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        canvas.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private int program;

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
        GL4 gl = glad.getGL().getGL4();
        gl.glClearColor(0.392f, 0.584f, 0.929f, 1.0f);
        program = gl.glCreateProgram();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
        GL4 gl = glad.getGL().getGL4();

        //     gl.glFlush();

        gl.glGenBuffers(1, vertexbuffer, 0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer[0]);
        gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufPos.capacity(), bufPos, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer[0]);

        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
                0,
                3,
                GL.GL_FLOAT,
                false,
                0,
                0
        );

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glad, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JOGL n = new JOGL();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely not create a new buffer in every frame. Create it one and then just use it in the display function. But the problem might come from this: `bufPos.capacity()` gives you the number of floats in the buffer, not the number of bytes. You will have to multiply it by `Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT`.

Comment: There's a lot missing here. Even if the tutorials you find are in C++, you should still be able to follow the code flow. For example, you have `glClear()` at the end of your `display()` method. This belongs at the start, because you want to clear the framebuffer **before** you start drawing, and not wipe out everything at the end. You're creating a shader program, but then never set it up or use it.

Comment: Here you go, a simple modern [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Comment: You can use Xerxes' example and mine too: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial Elect's example above doesn't use deprecated functions. I agree with Reto Koradi and you could have avoided to do some basic mistakes by looking at my example (even though it doesn't use VBO): https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98 Reminder: this one is mentioned on Wikipedia, you can't miss it.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is really what i needed!